# Pinning webhook message

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a webhook message then immediately pin the same message. Here's the code:

```
webhookClient.send({
        content: 'x',
        username: 'x',
        avatarURL: 'x',
        embeds: [embed],
    }).then(msg => {
    msg.pin()
    })
```

but I'm getting the error `TypeError: msg.pin is not a function`

Answer (score -1):

It attempted to call a value from a function, but the value is not a function. Some code expects you to provide a function, but that didn't happen.

Maybe there is a typo in the function name? Maybe the object you are calling the method on does not have this function? For example, JavaScript Objects have no map function, but the JavaScript Array object does.

So try using an array instead.